# "considered" or "mentioned"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

One article mentioned one valuable extension for their work (as a future work). I would like to say this in a sentence. However, I do not know what is the correct word to use.

> This extension was **considered** as a future work by A.

or

> This extension was **mentioned** as a future work by A.

Please note that I am not asking for proofreading, I just wonder which word can best describe the meaning of my sentence. For me, I think both are correct. However, the first sentence says that the authors consider this extension as a future work (they plan to do it as a future work). However, the second one says that this extension was mentioned as future work. But I am not sure if my understanding is correct or not.

Comment: "This extension was mentioned as a future work by A." would be appropriate to go with. However, "This extension was considered [to be] a future work by A." would be fine too.

Comment: @ZeeshanAli Thank you so much for your comment. Do that mean my understanding is correct?

Comment: In both cases, however, contexts are different. "B was considered to be C" becomes kinda understood when you say "B was mentioned to be C" whereas the converse is not true.

Answer (score 1):

They describe two slightly different things. *Considering* (thinking about; planning) doesn't require *mentioning* (stating, saying or writing). In this context they would be quite similar, and both applicable, although emphasizing different things. 'Considered' implies a thought process - someone was putting a thought into it, regarded pros and cons to reach a decision. It's not stating in any way how we know that it happened. 'Mentioned' focuses on passing the information on the decision to others, publishing the intent.

Both work fine and it's up to you which aspect you prefer to emphasize.